# border size change if i zoom the page

Tags: html, css

guys I just can not understand ...

I have set:

```
border: 2px solid #646464;
```

2px but not always, in fact according to the page zoom, ranges from 1.4px and 2px ...
yet I have no js code that modifies the size of the border ...

How is it possible????

see jsfiddle and change zoom

http://jsfiddle.net/00zv3zLy/

the height of box "log in" and box where is search bar it should be the same...but when change zoom it is not the same (because the border size of searchbar change)...

[image]

**ARE NOT THE SAME**

[image]

**ARE THE SAME**

I THINK THAT: when you zoom a page size change with the same proportion. If a div 100 px becomes 50px, then a span of 200px to 100px become. HERE the size of the border does not respect this proportion!

Comment: seriously??? so I post images

Comment: AND NOW
REMOVE THE NEGATIVE VOTE thanks!

Comment: @Jonathan But the proportions should not be equal?

Comment: absurd .... not even an answer, here we give a negative vote and leave. In fact I had to put screenshots in order to show that the heights were not equal. I BELIEVE THAT: when you zoom a page size change with the same proportion. If a div 100 px becomes 50px, then a span of 200px to 100px become. HERE the size of the border does not respect this proportion!

Comment: That's just an artifact caused by your browser and AFAIK there's nothing you can do with it. The fiddle works fine using chrome, but there are border inequality when tested with safari (different from what OP described). So I guess you can only treat this as an browser fault.

Comment: All the browsers use different rendering engines and they've been improving over time. What browser are you using? Yes, if you zoom out far enough the border becomes tiny, because everything else becomes tiny.

Comment: These are constructive answers !! use mozilla firefox! gazie ... so it's a browser issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome is better at sub pixel rendering so the issue is usually not observed, but many browsers will round things to integer number of pixels, which will cause similar problems as this one.

When your border is 2px and you scale by 0.7, you get 1.4px and might be rounded to 1px by some browser (eating up 0.8px considering both sides of the element). When there's lots of rounding piling around (such as paddings, margins, height etc.), you may loose a sum of 2px to 4px which could be quite significant.